# Cascade persistence fails to generate primary key for a new entity, why?

Tags: java, jpa, openjpa

This is the code:

```
@Entity
public class Dept {
  @Id 
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
  private Integer id;
  @OneToMany(
    mappedBy = "dept",
    cascade = CascadeType.ALL
  )
  private List<Employee> employees = new ArrayList<Employee>();
  public void addEmployee(Employee emp) {
    this.employees.add(emp);
  }
}

@Entity
public class Employee {
  @Id 
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
  private Integer id;
  @Column private Integer age;
  public Employee(Integer a) {
    this.age = a;
  }
}
```

Then in a unit test I'm doing this (OpenJPA is used):

```
// ...
Dept dept = new Dept();
dept.addEmployee(new Employee(25));
this.em.persist(dept);
```

OpenJPA says:

```
Caused by: <openjpa-1.2.1-r752877:753278 nonfatal general error>
org.apache.openjpa.persistence.PersistenceException: Attempt to insert 
null into a non-nullable column: column: ID table: EMPLOYEE in 
statement [INSERT INTO employee (age) VALUES (?)] 
{prepstmnt 841687127 INSERT INTO employee (age) VALUES (?) 
[params=(int) 25]} [code=-10, state=23000]
```

Why ID is not auto-generated?

Comment: You should probably check your code :
@Column private Integer age;
  public Employee(Integer age) {
    this.age = age;
  }

Comment: Do you have an attribute for department from Employee side. This seems to be missing in the code. The mapped by means, the side is the owning entity. Try removing mappedby and than doing the persist.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You one-to-many relationship is mapped as bidirectional (due to `mappedBy`), but I can't see the other side. Perhaps it's the cause.

And even if many-to-one side actually exists, it's not initialized in your code though it's an owning side of the relationship, therefore it specifies the state to be reflected in the database.

If you actually mean unidirectional relationship, you need to remove `mappedBy`.